# Secure Docker infrastructure on Hetzner

Tags: docker, hosting, infrastructure

I want to get a root server at Hetzner (https://www.hetzner.de/) and I'm asking myself how it is possible to secure the whole infrastructure.

I'll use Ubuntu as the hosting OS and then it would be good the secure ssh connections via VPN.
How is it possible to have VPN there?

Anything I should take care regarding hosting security with docker?

As you can see from my questions I'm a total newbie regarding infrastructure/hosting, but I'm willing to read also lots of stuff for learning this.
So if you can maybe recommend something or are there any tutorials or online classes?